# What is wrong with this UIAlertAction code? Won't allow a click/tap and move forward in the app

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm enrolled in a Swift/iOS Bootcamp course on Udemy. I've not had any issues prior to this one with any of the code or lessons, but this has me stumped. The module is about setting up UIAlertController and UIAlertAction, and resetting a quiz app to the beginning of the quiz. The quiz works as it should (at this point at least), however, once the Alert pops up, I can't click on it. It doesn't recognize any of the taps or clicks or move forward to the function that should be called when the click is received.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw4KJ.jpg

I'm following the code as written in the course, but one of the issues could possibly be that the course is using an older version of Swift/Xcode than I am, but I'm not 100% positive. That *could* be causing some confusion.

However, I have tried to utilize the Apple API Documentation, at one point, copying all of their sample code and adjusting to fit my needs (in terms of function to call after 'OK'), but even that code didn't register a click. I've searched on Stack, altered code based on other forums, and nothing has worked.

```
func nextQuestion() {

    if questionNumber <= allQuestions.list.count - 1 {

        var nextQuestion = allQuestions.list[questionNumber]

        questionLabel.text = nextQuestion.questionText
    }
    else {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Quiz Over", message: "You've Finished the Quiz, Press Restart to Start Over", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in 

              self.startOver()
        }

        alert.addAction(restartAction)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

As mentioned, the 'Restart' button on the Alert should force the quiz to restart. The startOver() function resets the questionNumber to 0, and calls a nextQuestion() function, as well as printing a line for me to know if the function has been called, which would mean that the tap is registered, but the startOver() function is incorrect, but it won't print the line, which indicates that the function isn't being called at all.

Full ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //Place your instance variables here
    let allQuestions = QuestionBank()
    var pickedAnswer : Bool = false
    var questionNumber : Int = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var progressBar: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let firstQuestion = allQuestions.list[0]
        questionLabel.text = firstQuestion.questionText

    }


    @IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        if sender.tag == 1 {
            pickedAnswer = true
        }
        else if sender.tag == 2 {
            pickedAnswer = false
        }

        checkAnswer()
        nextQuestion()
    }


    func updateUI() {

    }


    func nextQuestion() {
        questionNumber += 1

        if questionNumber <= allQuestions.list.count - 1 {

            var nextQuestion = allQuestions.list[questionNumber]

            questionLabel.text = nextQuestion.questionText
        }
        else {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Quiz Over", message: "You've Finished the Quiz, Press Restart to Start Over", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default) { action in self.startOver()
            }

            alert.addAction(restartAction)

            self.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }


    func checkAnswer() {
        if pickedAnswer == allQuestions.list[questionNumber].answer{
            print("good")
        }
        else if pickedAnswer != allQuestions.list[questionNumber].answer{
            print("bad")
        }


    }


    func startOver() {
        questionNumber = -1
        nextQuestion()
        print(questionNumber)
        print("Restarting")

    }



}
```

Comment: Does alert dismiss if you tap the Restart button? Your code doesn't actually do anything when the button is tapped but at least the alert should dismiss.

Comment: @rmaddy, No, it does not dismiss when the Restart button is pressed. It does absolutely nothing. Can click on it dozens of times, no change.

Comment: @matt I made the change to 'action in' instead, but no change. Still won't dismiss, or move on from the Alert.

Comment: share content of `startOver`

Comment: The UIAlertController is fine, try replace self.startOver() with print("something").
And "UIAlertAction" should not be used as variable although it's working.

Comment: `func startOver() {
    print(questionNumber)
    print("Restarting")
    questionNumber = 0
    nextQuestion()
    }
`
This should at least print "Restarting", but it's not even getting to that point. The Alert just remains on screen and no amount of clicking gets rid of it.

Comment: print something, instead of calling startOver(), and tell us if this works

Comment: Some sort of loop with alerts happend

Comment: @DavidDavidoff Tried that, same thing...

` else {
            
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Quiz Over", message: "You've Finished the Quiz, Press Restart to Start Over", preferredStyle: .alert)
            
            let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default) { action in print("Test")
            }
            
            alert.addAction(restartAction)
            
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
`

Comment: could you please share the whole contents of the view controller?

Comment: Just downloaded this app from github – everything works. The original app have also some kind of toast when you press a button. I think after the alert is displayed you also show some other element which covers the alert

Comment: PS: you also don't increment the `questionNumber` in `nextQuestion()` function

Comment: @AndreyGershengoren I have uploaded the ViewController as an edit above. I don't really care about the app, just want to learn what's going on (since I'm following the course code, but it's not working). The `questionNumber` will make more sense above! This works now, but the restart is slow. Takes a minute or so, and don't yet know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce any issue based on the code you've shown, as you can see:

[image]

... so I think this is may be a problem with your Xcode setup. Possible issue:

- You are building to the iPhone XR simulator which is slow.
- You may have an old computer.
- And you seem to have turned on Slow Animations in the Simulator app by mistake.

At the least try turning off Slow Animations and build for the 5s simulator. This will make the Simulator a lot more responsive. But on old machinery there may still be issues.

Comment: Indeed, the issue was that the "Slow Animations" setting was on. Either it was activated automatically when I first started up the app (and didn't realize it), or I may have hit Command-T thinking I was in Safari to open a tab, but instead activated the Slow Animations.

When I removed that, it worked perfectly when `animated: false`, so I set `animated: true` and it worked perfectly again! So I turned Slow back on tested `true` and it didn't appear to work again. I had to let the Alert stay on screen for a minute or so before I could click on it. It wouldn't recognize the tap right away!

Comment: I still think you have a hardware issue. Are you running in some kind of emulator? Your slow animation is VERY slow.

Comment: I'm not running an emulator. Late 2017 MBP running Mojave. Seemed slow, but I didn't have anything to compare it to!

Answer (score 0):

Try to present in main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

Comment: @ItHertz you have custom animation, for alert presentation. What have you done to add it?

Comment: Changing the `animated: true` to `animated: false` worked! I don't know *how* to animate, or create a custom animation. I simply followed what the course code/video showed by setting it to true. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @ItHertz it should also work with animation true, in normal case scenario, but you have something in your code, that preventing from it. Do you have UIView.animate somewhere in your code?

Comment: No, I don't have UIView.animate anywhere... It was/is certainly frustrating!